# How to get the format from the string in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new in JSON format. I have tried to retrieve the format of a string in JSON mode. I have applied the format by specifying {0:n2} to a td which perfectly working. Now i have tried to retrieve the format({0:n2}) from the td text, but i cant get it.

For example:

If i have applied a format {0:n2} to a td then the value becomes "0.00", Now i have tried to retrieve the format from the td text "0.00", I don't know how to do this...

I tried to get the result as "{0:n2}"

If anyone knows how to retrieve the format of the string, please help me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a deserializer; use the native browser implementations: var TheObjectFromJson = JSON.parse(YourJsonString); There's no such thing as "the format of a string in json".

Comment: thanks for the reply frenchie. I have tried it, but it returns the parse value. JSON.parse("0.00") returns 0 value.

Comment: Please past your code from what you tried

Comment: JSON.parse("0.00") is supposed to return 0. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. If you want to format it, then leave it as a string. You can use JSON.parse to convert the string to a number and then use myNumber.toFixed(2) to format it back to a string with two decimals.

Comment: yes, JSON.parse("0.00") will return 0.

Comment: What are you trying to do??? "Now i have tried to retrieve the format({0:n2}) from the td text, but i cant get it." Can you paste your JSON string and the desired end-result?

Comment: I'd like to understand more what you would like to do in the td to JSON. I think is a "translate" function FROM {0:n2} to 0.00 and FROM 0.00 to {0:n2} where n2 means two zero? If that's the case let me know and it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is in essence a string that can be closely matched to a javascript object. So it isn't difficult to convert it to a native javascript object. Use JSON.parse() for this purpose. Some examples from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
try {
  JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
  JSON.parse('true');            // true
  JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
  JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
  JSON.parse('null');            // null
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Parsing error:", e); 
}
```

If I understand what you are trying to achieve, you can format the native number back to a string with two decimals with this function: `var myFormattedString = myNumber.toFixed(2);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply zszep, but my need is to retrieve the format which one i have already applied to the string. If the string is "0.00" then the result will be "{0:n2}"... My need is to get the format "{0:n2}".